# Relations among words

Tags: connect-wall

The set of sixteen terms below can be partitioned. Each partition is of four terms that have something in common. I invite you to figure out the partitions and commonalities. (The four commonalities do not, themselves, have something in common.)

ABSCOND, CHEEK, DISCERN, FULL TIME, GROUCH, GUM, HARP, INVENT, PROBOSCIS, RECESS, RENOVATE, SILVER, SLAP, SPIDER, SQUIRREL, THEFT

Hint, added later:

> Two partitions' criteria are directly related to the meanings of the words in the partitions. The other two's are not.

Another two hints, added even later:

> Instead of DISCERN, I could have included CANOODLE;

and

> instead of THEFT, I should probably have included SHOPLIFTING.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

I believe one set is

> Grouch, Harp, Cheek, Gum  - the Marx Brothers (Groucho, Harpo, Chico, Gummo)

Comment: One group really isn't enough for a [connect-wall] partial answer, because there can be many false groups of four. At least 3 groups, or 2 extremely well-defined ones, is a minimum that has verifiable progress.